# Get panel expand tool reference in border layout when panel is collapsed

Tags: extjs, extjs5

How to get panel  collapse (expand) tool reference in border layout when panel is collapsed?

I can only get the collapse tool (left) reference and not the expand tool (right) when panel is collapsed.

Fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tlv

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expand tool is on a [placeholder](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.1/api/Ext.panel.Panel.html#cfg-placeholder) component within the panel, rather than a tool of the panel itself.

You can reach the expand-right tool with `panel.getPlaceholder().tools["expand-right"]`

I've updated your [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1tm4) with this.

Comment: Thanks Jaimee. Works great.